# Volume of region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\binom{n}2$ linear constraints

Tags: probability, geometry, determinant, volume

What is the volume of the region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $0 \le x_i \le 1$ for all $1 \le i \le n$ and $x_i +x_j \ge 1$ for all pairs $1\le i<j \le n$?

For example for $n=2$, this is just the upper triangle of the unit square which is $1/2$.

Alternatively, if $n$ iid uniform random variables are drawn in $[0,1]$, what is the probability that every pair of them add to at least $1$?

Comment: I probably didn't fully understand your challenge. But it seems to me that for $n=3$ the volume of the specified region is equal to $1-1/6$. In the general case the formula $1-1/n!$ is obtained. Or is it?

Comment: Take $n=2$. This means we want the portion of the unit square that satisfies $x+y \ge 1$ which has probability $1/2$. For $n=3$, we want the volume of the unit cube that satisfies $x+y \ge 1, x+z \ge 1, z+y \ge 1$. This is $1/4$.

Comment: I agree, I see where I was going astray. It's a very interesting question.

Comment: The answer is $\color{red}{2^{1-n}}$, but I didn't find a proof yet.

Comment: For what it matters, the probabilistic interpretation leads directly to $\mathbb{P}[U_{(1)} + U_{(2)} \geq 1]$, where $U_{(i)}$ is the $i$th order statistic from a sample of $n$ standard uniform random variables.  We know [a lot about these, including their joint distribution,](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Order_statistic&oldid=1194980969#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics) so we can solve it using that route (as mentioned in a previous comment, it does give $2^{1-n}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized Brian Moehring's observation directly gives the answer (without the need for any fancy formulas). If we let $U_{(1)}$ and $U_{(2)}$ be the smallest and second smallest values out of the $n$ uniformly random numbers, then we just want $P(U_{(1)} + U_{(2)} \ge 1)$. But this is a straightforward calculation.

We know $n(1-t)^{n-1}$ is the density function of $U_{(1)}$. Furthermore, given $U_{(1)}$, the rest of the variables are just iid uniform in $[U_{(1)}, 1]$. Thus, given $U_{(1)}$, the probability that $U_{(2)}$ is at least $1-U_{(1)}$ is just the probability that all of the $n-1$ draws land in the interval $[1-U_{(1)}, 1]$, which has relative length $U_{(1)}/(1-U_{(1)})$. However, we have to be slightly careful because once $U_{(1)} \ge 1/2$, the event always holds.

$$Pr(U_{(1)} + U_{(2)} \ge 1) = n\int_0^{1/2} (1-t)^{n-1} \cdot \left( \frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{n-1} \ dt + P(U_{(1)} \ge 1/2).$$

Both of these terms are $2^{-n}$ so the final answer is $2^{-n+1}$.